# Show that the following matrix is positive definite.

Tags: matrices

Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times N}$, with $M > N$, and $R \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times M}$ is a diagonal matrix. Show that the matrix $$A^{H}RA$$ is positive definite if $$Re(r_{ii}) > 0$$Here $r_{ii}$ are the diagonal elements of the diagonal matrix $R$.

Attempt: Considering that the Null space of $A$ is ${\vec{0}}$, if we consider the term
$$Re[(u)^HR(u)]$$ where $u = Av, v \in \mathbb{C}^{N}$, where $v$ is an arbitrary vector, then it seems true. Although I am not sure if I am on the right track.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How do you define a complex non-Hermitian matrix to be positive definite? $x^H(A^HRA)x$ does not even need to be real.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel The matrix in question is hermitian. My belief is that the eigenvalues of it are simply the diagonal elements of R. But I am not sure

Comment: Is $R$ a *real* diagonal matrix then? if it is not, then $A^HRA$ is not Hermitian.

Comment: Yes. Sorry. Edited it.

Comment: Well, then since $A$ has supposedly full column rank, then $x\neq 0$ implies $y=Ax\neq 0$. So for any nonzero $x$, $x^H(A^HRA)x=y^HRy$ for some nonzero $y$ and since $R$ is real diagonal with positive entries, $y^HRy=\sum_ir_{ii}|y_i|^2>0$.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel I suggest you write this as an answer

Comment: Is it true that in case R was complex, it is sufficient and nec. to show that the Hermitian part of the above matrix is pos. def?